# Limitation of anonymous classes in java?

Tags: java, class, nested

I have been facing so many problem using the anonymous class like I can't perform the instanceOf test neither can I implements multiple interface, so could someone please explain what I can or can not do with the anonymous class in java ?

Comment: "what I can or can not do with the nested class" -- not all *nested* classes are *anonymous*.

Comment: In addition to the two items that you listed, anonymous classes cannot have constructors.

Comment: what is wrong with this example:public class nestedExample {
 public void outer (new innerClass(){
  public inner(){
   System.out.println("this is inner");
  }
 });
 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  nestedExample ex= new nestedExample();
  ex.outer();
 }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of an anonymous inner class is to extend and instantiate an existing class or implement a single interface in one step.

Its limitations can be derived from the above:

- Only one non-final class can be extended or one interface implemented.
- Only final local variables of the enclosing method can be accessed. (This is due to the fact that normal local variables will be out of scope by the time any methods of the inner class will be invoked.)
- You can't define a constructor. (The class has no name.)

If you need multiple interfaces, you can use a local inner class, which is like a normal inner class, with its own name, but defined within a method. I have to admit I've never seen it used in practice and I see very little reason for anyone to do so, hopefully someone will come up with an example.

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous classes work whenever

- you never need to refer to the class itself
- you only need to extend a single class or implement a single interface

...but other than that there aren't really any significant constraints.  This works fine in a lot of cases: for example, many cases when you're defining callbacks, listeners, or the like.